# Alternative to Geneva Framework

Tags: .net, geneva-framework

Are there any alternatives to [Microsoft Geneva Framework](https://connect.microsoft.com/site/sitehome.aspx?SiteID=642) (preferably open source). We have planed to use it in production environment, but it looks like that Microsoft has license that doesn't allow that while the Geneva Framework is in beta.

Comment: It's typical that you are not really allowed to use a Beta product, because it's typically free while the final product is not. The Beta exists to let you play with it (and report bugs) until the final product arrives. So if you're fine with Geneva and expect it to be released in time (and the price is ok with you as well), develop with the Beta now and switch to the Release once it's there, then there's no problem with the license. But that doesn't answer your question for alternatives, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Afraid not. It's a massively new approach, and so there's no open source, or any other alternative. Depending on what you want to do you may be able to pick and choose, but for full claims based authentication and authorization then Geneva is it right now.

Comment: fine answer, could you please provide some alternative, even tough it won't be as integral as geneva? thanks a lot...

Comment: It depends what you want to do of course. For full blown claims based auth there's nothing else. For STS development there's sharpsts, although I kind of stopped developing that as no-one but me used it. For cardspace acceptance there's very brittle sample code knocking about, but I don't recommend its use.

Answer (score 0):

I am in the same boat.. I just started looking into the Java Central Authentication Service
http://www.jasig.org/cas. I am hoping I can get it running with configuration and connect my asp.net apps via the web services.